# Using subsurface modifier on circle

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

So, I'm trying to use a subsurface modifier on my mesh, but it displays weirdly... I know how to use edge loops on a square side, but how can I make this work on a circle side ? 
[image: Example]

The bottom face is made as best as I could, by merging two extruded vertices.

Comment: The Subsurface Modifier (and others) work best with "Quad" based mesh. You have a huge N-gon on the bottom of your mesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the bottom face and use the **INSET TOOL** (Hotkey : I) to adjust.

But Keep in mind you have a N-GON(poly with more than 4 verts) down there, and subsurf and ngons don't work great together.

You can fix this deleting the NGON face, select all the boundary verts, extrude the verts/edges and scale them to the center

[image]

Comment: This worked. However. if its triangles instead of quads, does it still do the same thing ? Because to do what you're doing in the gif it makes triangles, not quads.

Comment: Indeed there's tris on the center, but there's no mesh importance in there so the subsurf don't mess anything. N-GONS aren't bad, the problem is the subsurf can produce shading imperfections, and some external engines can't handle NGONS that good, but keep in mynd, at the end every poly will be converted to tris(especially in game engines)